# how to test carrierwave fog google in rspec with setting up the configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog, fog-google

I have below configuration and I wanted to write TC for it in ruby. I am new to ruby and wanted to understand how we can set the configuration of Fog to point to mock and use it in test-case.

```
class TestUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def fog_credentials
    {
      :provider => 'google',
      :google_project =>'my project',
      :google_json_key_location =>'myCredentialFile.json'

    }
  end


  def fog_provider
    'fog/google'
  end

  def fog_directory
    '{#bucket-name}'
  end

  def store_dir

    when :File
      "#{file.getpath}/file"
    when :audio
      "#{file.getpath}/audio"
    else
      p " Invalid file "
    end
  end
end
```

```
class TestModel

  mount_uploader :images, TestUploader

end
```

Could someone please assist me from configuring to write and execute the unit test on it with few example. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the test I did, I got the following sample code working with Google Cloud Storage using Fog gem:

```rb
require "fog/google"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to use Mock
#Fog.mock!

# Bucket name
bucket = "an-existing-bucket"

# Timestamp used as sample string
test = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider => "Google",
  :google_project => "your-project",
  :google_json_key_location => "path-to-key.json",
})

# Lists objects in a bucket
puts connection.list_objects(bucket)

#Creates new object
connection.put_object(bucket, test, test)
puts "Object #{test} was created."
```

It works in production, but fails using mock mode with the following error:

```rb
`not_implemented': Contributions welcome! (Fog::Errors::MockNotImplemented)
```

It seems that it is not implemented as shown at the [`put_object`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fog-google/1.19.0/Fog%2FStorage%2FGoogleJSON%2FMock:put_object) method definition in the documentation.

Also, this is said in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/issues/243):

> Closing issue. 1.0.0 is out, and we have no more mocks for json backed objects.

---

#### Credentials

As shown in the [Fog's documentation](https://fog.io/storage/#google-cloud-storage), to configure Google Credentials you have to them as follows:

```rb
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                         => 'Google',
  :google_storage_access_key_id     => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  :google_storage_secret_access_key => YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})
```

#### Mock

In the [GitHub - Fog::Google](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/README.md#foggoogle) documentation, there is also a [**minimal config**](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/README.md#carrierwave-integration) to integrate Fog with Carrierwave.

In order to use the [Cloud Storage mock](https://fog.io/storage/#mocking-out-cloud-storage), you can use the following line:

```rb
Fog.mock!
connection = Fog::Storage.new(config_hash)
```

#### Provider Specific Resources

In the [provider documentation](https://fog.io/about/provider_documentation.html) section, you will find links to provider specific documentation and examples.

> Community supported providers can get assistance by filing Github Issues on the appropriate repository.

| Provider | Documentation | Examples | Support Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | [Documentation](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/README.md) | [fog-google-examples](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/tree/master/examples) | Community |

> *In order to maximize the benefits of open source, you are encouraged submit bugs to [Github Issues](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues)*

In this [GitHub example](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/examples/storage_json.rb), you could find an implementation for Google Cloud Storage.

#### Class List

At the [RubyGems documentation for fog-google](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fog-google/1.19.0/Fog/Storage/GoogleJSON/Real), you can find the class definitions and parameters. For example, the [`list_objects`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fog-google/1.19.0/Fog/Storage/GoogleJSON/Real#list_objects-instance_method) method:

> `#list_objects(bucket, options = {}) ⇒ Google::Apis::StorageV1::Objects`
> Lists objects in a bucket matching some criteria.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `bucket` (String) — Name of bucket to list
> - `options` (Hash) (defaults to: {}) — Optional hash of options
>   Options Hash (`options`):
> - `:delimiter (String)` — Delimiter to collapse objects under to emulate a directory-like mode
> - `:max_results (Integer)` — Maximum number of results to retrieve
> - `:page_token (String)` — Token to select a particular page of results
> - `:prefix (String)` — String that an object must begin with in order to be returned
> - `:projection ("full", "noAcl")` — Set of properties to return (defaults to “noAcl”)
> - `:versions (Boolean)` — If true, lists all versions of an object as distinct results (defaults to False)
>
> Returns:
>
> - `(Google::Apis::StorageV1::Objects)`