# Settting up environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, carrierwave, google-cloud-storage, fog-google

I am trying to setup the service-account and storing the credential file inside linux server and storing the path in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` provided by Google.

It is said that Google Cloud Client Libraries use a library called Application Default Credentials (ADC) to automatically find your service account credentials.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

I am using CarrierWave inside this fog:google library to upload and download the files. Could you please assist or share your thoughts how can we use in this libraries.

My CarrierWave uploader implementation is below:

```
class TestUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def fog_credentials
    {
      :provider => 'google',
      :google_project =>'my project',
      :google_json_key_location => GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    }
  end

  def fog_provider
    'fog/google'
  end

  def fog_directory
    '{#bucket-name}'
  end

  def store_dir

    when :File
      "#{file.getpath}/file"
    when :audio
      "#{file.getpath}/audio"
    else
      p " Invalid file "
    end
  end
end
```

I tried it but it did not work. Kindly suggest here.

Comment: hi , can you try this [link](https://github.com/metaware/carrierwave-google-storage) is it helpful?

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [Github issue](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/issues/243) stated as:

```
Closing issue. 1.0.0 is out, and we have no more mocks for json backed objects.
```

You can also check the [Documentation](https://github.com/metaware/carrierwave-google-storage) for google cloud storagee implementation  where mentioned as :

> Use the official google-cloud gem by Google for Google Cloud Storage,
> instead of Fog. No need to activate Interoperable Access on your
> project. Rely on Google's preferred authentication mechanism. ie:
> Service Accounts.

As mentioned in the Stackoverflow [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73039987/15774176):

You can see this code:

> Google Cloud Storage using Fog gem: ```ruby
>
> ```
> require "fog/google"
>
> # Uncomment the following line if you want to use Mock
> #Fog.mock!
>
> # Bucket name
> bucket = "an-existing-bucket"
>
> # Timestamp used as sample string
> test = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
>
> connection = Fog::Storage.new({
>   :provider => "Google",
>   :google_project => "your-project",
>   :google_json_key_location => "path-to-key.json",
> })
>
> # Lists objects in a bucket
> puts connection.list_objects(bucket)
>
> #Creates new object
> connection.put_object(bucket, test, test)
> puts "Object #{test} was created."
> ``
> ```

`

Comment: @sagar verma Posted an answer, Is it helpful?